# Navigation Bar won't collapse

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

After clicking on the icon the navigation menu expands, after selecting an item it brings me to the correct section but doesn't collapse.

Sorry I wasn't sure how much more code I should add I'll work on what you gave me and strip out the other stuff so I can submit more of it later on.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-offset="0" data-target="#navbar-main">
  <div id="navbar-main">
    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon icon-hammer" style="font-size:30px; color:#3498db;"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs hidden-sm" href="#home"><span class="icon icon-hammer" style="font-size:18px; color:#3498db;"></span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li> <a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">Home</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#about" class="smoothScroll"> About</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#walkways" class="smoothScroll"> Walkways</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#patios" class="smoothScroll"> Patio's</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#walls" class="smoothScroll"> Walls</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#fireplace" class="smoothScroll"> Fireplace</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#team" class="smoothScroll"> Team</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll"> Contact</a></li>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you give complete code? Seems like I couldn't find where the lines of code that you wrong

Comment: I got kicked off of Stack overflow, and I have to improve my questions but I no longer do HTML this was five years ago, hopefully if I work on my other questions I can get back in.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the other parts in the code

This is an example of their responsive navbar header from the following page
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default
Please note the following

```
class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"
```

So you need to add that, with the data-target being the id or class of the nav div you are trying to expand

```
<div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
```